# Is there a way to make crontab run a gnu screen session?

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a discord bot running on a raspberry pi that i need to restart every day, I'm trying to do this through crontab but with no luck.

It manages to kill the active screen processes but never starts an instance, not that I can see with "screen -ls" and I can tell that it doesn't create one that I can't see as the bot itself does not come online.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pkill screen
sleep 2
screen -dmS discordBot
sleep 2
screen -S "discordBot" -X stuff "node discordBot/NEWNEWNEWN\n"
```

Here is also the crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/admin/discordBot/script.sh
```

Is it possible to have crontab run a screen session? And if so how?

Previously I tried putting the screen command stright into cron but now I have it in a bash script instead.
If I run the script in the terminal it works perfectly, it’s just cron where it fails. Also replacing "screen" with the full path "/usr/bin/screen" does not change anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the best way of doing it, without investigating the underlying problem would be to create a systemd service and putting a restart command into cron.

`/etc/systemd/system/mydiscordbot.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A very simple discord bot

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=node /path/to/my/discordBot.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now you can run your bot with `systemctl start mydiscordbot` and can view your logs with `journalctl --follow -u mydiscord bot`

Now you only need to put

```
45 2 * * * systemctl restart discordbot
```

into root's crontab and you should be good to go.

You probably should also write the logs into a logfile, maybe `/var/log/mydiscordbot.log`, but how and if you do that is up to you.

---

**OLD/WRONG ANSWER:**

cron is run with a minimal environment, and depending on your os, /usr/bin/ is probably not in the $PATH var. screen is mostlikely located at /usr/bin/screen, so cron can't run it because it can't find the screen binary. try replacing `screen` in your script with `/usr/bin/screen`

But the other question here is: Why does your discord bot need to be restarted every day. I run multiple bots with 100k+ users, and they don't need to be restarted at all. Maybe you should open a new question with the error and some code snippets.

Comment: Should've mentioned that replacing "screen" with "/usr/bin/screen" does not help, but yes that is where it is located. As to why the bot needs to be restarted, it stops recieving commands after a week or two, and debugging is something I don't want to sink time into at the moment as I have nothing to go on. I appreciate the subtle brag and criticism, but that's not what my question is about.

Comment: Didn't meant to brag, i just wanted to give a reference, that having to restart is not normal behaivour. :)

Comment: There is an whole other way you could go about this tho: You could get rid of the screen at all, convert your script to a systemd service and put a restart command for that service into crontab. If you want to go that route, i can make another answer.

Comment: Ah, never thought of doing it that way, I assume the only way to get output would be through a log file if you do it that way?

Comment: Yes and no. I strongly recommend to write to a logfile, e.g. /var/log/discord/bot.log, but every process that is run via systemd and produces console output gets written to the system journal. so you can also view the log via journalctl -u mydiscordbot

Comment: In any case, doing it this way worked wonders, and actually makes way more sense than what I was doing previously. If you just want to change/add another answer about using a systemd service instead I'll check ya.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what os your rpi is running, but I had a similar issue earlier today trying to get vms on a server to launch a terminal and run a python script with crontab. I found a very easily solution to automatically restart it on crashes, and to run something simply in the background.  Don't rely on crontab or an init service. If your rpi as an x server running, or anything that can be launched on session start, there is a simple shell solution.  Make  a bash script like

```bash
while :; do
    /my/script/to/keep/running/here -foo -bar -baz >> /var/log/myscriptlog 2>&1
done
```

and then you would start it on .xprofile or some similar startup operation like

```bash
/path/to/launcher.sh &
```

to have it run the background. It will restart automatically everytime it closes if started in something like .xprofile, .xinitrc, or anything ran at startup.

Then maybe make a cronjob to restart the raspberry pi or whatever system is running the script but this script wil restart the service whenever it's closed anyway. Maybe you can put that cronjob on a script but I don't think it would launch the GUI.

Some other things you can do to launch a GUI terminal in my research with cronjob that you can try, though they didn't work for my situation on these custom linux vms, and that I read was a security risk to do this from a cronjob, is you can specify the display.

```bash
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /your/gui/stuff/here
```

but you would would need to make sure the user has the right permissions and it's considered an unsafe hack to even do this as far as I have read.

for my issue, I had to launch a terminal that stayed open, and then changed to the directory of a python script and ran the script, so that the local files in directory would be called in the python script. here is a rough example of the "launcher.sh" I called from the startup method this strange linux distro used lol.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
    /usr/bin/urxvt -e /bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/project && python loader.py"
done
```

Also check this source for process management
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Comment: I might be just understanding you incorrectly due to my lack of sleep, but I don't see how running a script permanently in the background helps. I'm running rpi OS lite and ssh into the rpi. So I use screen so I can start the bot in there, detatch it, and close the ssh session without it the node instance being terminated. There is no need for a reboot of the entire rpi, just the screen instance, I actually only need to send 2 commands in the screen session but the cronjob doesn't want to.